# Generating Set for $O(V)$ over $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: lie-groups, linear-algebra, gt.geometric-topology

I am reading a claim that $O(V)$ — the orthogonal group associated with a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb Z_2$ and a quadratic form $q$, i.e. the group of linear transformations $T:V\to V$ with $q(v)=q(T(v))$ — 
 is finitely-generated (and its generators are known), because of the Cartan–Dieudonné theorem.

Now, the Cartan–Dieudonné theorem states that if $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$, then $n$ is generated by *at most* $n$ reflections.  My confusion here is that since we are working over $\mathbb Z_2$, orthogonal transformations are also symplectic, and the symplectic group is known to be finitely-generated by transvections (the generalization to vector spaces of shear maps in $\mathbb R^n$).

Anyway, I am trying to figure out a generating set for $O(V)$ as defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I got it; I was looking at the wrong Dieudonne source.

Comment: It would be most convenient for us if you posted a brief explanation as an answer (so the software recognizes the question as resolved), or deleted the question.

Comment: Sure; the Dieudonne source is :  La geommetrie des groupes clasiques (3rd. ed), Ergebnisse der Math u.i Grundz.5, springer, 1971. The maps are the $Z_2$ transvections (in this context) defined on H_1(Sg,Z/2) by: T_z(x):=x+(z,x)_2z, where (z,x)_2 is the intersection form in H_1(Sg,z/2) . Hope it helps anyone else interested.

Comment: @SeanLawton is it really necessary to persist in resurrecting all these old questions merely to introduce markup? Answering old questions is fine with me, but could you please explain your rationale for systematically going through all these old questions and making these changes?

Comment: @YemonChoi one reason can be because of stupid badges such as "copy editor" which require "Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)" or its silver counterpart ("edit 80 posts")

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't think this is best place for this discussion (chat room?).  That said, while I think MO is most valuable as a community to help researchers with their new questions, I also think it has value as a whole.  People reference and search old questions and answers. Tidying up the body as whole (at least from my point of view) is a worthwhile activity.  When we stir the pot from the bottom we encourage old questions to be answered or closed or other editors to further improve them.  Moreover, setting a standard on formatting/readability also informs new users about expectations.

Comment: @YemonChoi Do you know why was this question not automatically deleted?  It seems it had 0 score and was inactive for almost 5 years.  I don't know the SE cleanup method, but I thought I heard on multiple occasions that inactive questions with no upvotes are automatically deleted.